# Jquery Autocomplete & Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Just after a little help if possible,

Im using the Codeigniter framework and i have managed to get jQuery autocomplete working, with information from a mysql database.

But have come a little bit stuck on getting the results of the auto complete to show other information in text field.

Im just trying to get my head around Jquery at the moment but have very limited knowledge of it so any help or pointers would be a great help.

My JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function() {
    $( "#Name" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('autocomplete/namesuggestions'); ?>",
                data: { term: $("#Name").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
```

With Two input boxes with ids of Name   and another of Address

Just to make things a bit more confusing i can get the address to appear in the Name and address to appear in the  Name text box when it auto completes ??

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have to map the response for ajax responses and for fill other input box onselect you can use `select:` option in autocomplete like this

```
var source_name = {
        source:function(request, response){
            $.getJSON('your url and parameter as get',function(data){
                if(data != null){
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.name,
                            addr: item.addr
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui){
        $('#addr').val(ui.item.addr);

        }
    };

$('#Name').autocomplete( source_name);
```

This will work fine if you are using jquery ui and if you return your json properly as to get values. Hope This helps you.